# Correct attribution is impossible for failed sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange-2.0, copyright, attribution

Two of the attribution requirements in the data dumps are:

> 2. Hyperlink directly to the original question on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345)
>    4. Hyperlink each author name directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

This is impossible (without violating the spirit of the requirements) for failed sites like [Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), as there's nowhere to link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably fine in this case to link back to the proposal:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets

Comment: "*probably* fine"?!